Hi! I am trying to execute a function to hide rows on my GoogleSheet when the data validation selected is 'Completed'
The options in the dropdown are Completed, In Progress, and Followup. I only want to hide the row when Completed is selected. Is there a way to achieve this?
Tried the following function
function onEdit(e) { 
    const columns = [3]; 
    const { range } = e;
    if (!columns.includes(range.columnStart) || !range.isComplete()) return; 
    range.getSheet().hideRows(range.rowStart); 
}



You were close
From
function onEdit(e) { 
    const columns = [3]; 
    const { range } = e;
    if (!columns.includes(range.columnStart) || !range.isComplete()) return; 
    range.getSheet().hideRows(range.rowStart); 
}

To
function onEdit(e) { 
    const columns = [3]; 
    const { range, value } = e;
    if (!columns.includes(range.columnStart) || value !== 'Completed') return; 
    range.getSheet().hideRows(range.rowStart); 
}

Notes:

isCompleted() is not method of Class Range.
Beside the range property, the on edit event object might include a value property. This property is included when a single cell is edited, except if the cell value was cleared. The To version makes use of this property.

